# Scapy error! How can I resolve it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scapy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./a.py", line 124, in <module>
    from scapy.all import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/all.py", line 25, in <module>
    from route import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 162, in <module>
    conf.route=Route()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.resync()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 31, in resync
    self.routes = read_routes()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/unix.py", line 86, in read_routes
    ifaddr = scapy.arch.get_if_addr(netif)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/__init__.py", line 36, in get_if_addr
    return socket.inet_ntoa(get_if_raw_addr(iff))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/pcapdnet.py", line 200, in get_if_raw_addr
    i = dnet.intf()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'intf'
```

Comment: What is the output of `netstat -rn` on that machine?

Comment: Ah, it doesn't really matter what `netstat` outputs. The `dnet` package is not imported correctly. What does `python -c 'import dnet; print dnet'` output? You probably have another `dnet` module somewhere that is imported instead of the [scapy dependency](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/portability.html#generic).

Comment: <module 'dnet' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyDNET-0.92_r0-py2.7.egg/dnet/__init__.pyc'>

Comment: And `python -c 'import dnet; print dnet.inf()'` works?

Comment: No :( some error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'inf'

Comment: That doesn't look like the correct `dnet` package. That's not the correct [libdnet project](http://libdnet.sourceforge.net/); that would install as the `dnet` project, not `PyDNET`. How did you install it?

Comment: I installed dnet from here : https://github.com/takemaru/dnet

Comment: That is not the correct project, wherever you installed it from. Note the title: *Power Distribution Network Evaluation Tool*. You need to follow the scapy installation instructions.

Comment: now I do not longer reports the error first . but I say this: ImportError: No module named dnet.

Comment: Did you follow *all* instructions to install `libdnet` including the Python part? The `python setup.py install` ran successfully?

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong `dnet` package installed. You have [PyDNET](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDNET) (a project for analysing power distribution networks), but Scapy requires that [`libdnet`](http://libdnet.sourceforge.net/) (a low-level networking library) is installed instead.

The Scapy project includes [instructions on how to install `libdnet`](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/portability.html#generic). You may have to uninstall PyDNET.

The SourceForge hostnames changed; the correct instructions to get the CVS source code is:

```
cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@libdnet.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/libdnet login 
cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@libdnet.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/libdnet co -P libdnet
```

Comment: Now I installed pydnet but still the error :(

Comment: @GilloBottini: no, you should **not** install pydnet. You already had pydnet installed. *Remove it*. You need to install the `libdnet` project, as per the Scapy instructions I linked you to.

Comment: Can you link me a download of libdnet?

Comment: I've already linked you to the [instructions](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/portability.html#generic). You need to have the `csv` command.

Comment: I installed csv but when I do the first command responds with this error : Unknown host cvs.sourceforge.net .    :/

Comment: @GilloBottini: ah, yes, the hostnames at SourceForge changed. The correct URL is now `pserver:anonymous@libdnet.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/libdnet` (so insert `libdnet.`). I added that to my answer.